# Image post attachments not specific to post

Tags: wordpress

**My Issue:** I loaded several images in one post and thus they dynamically got assigned an attachment to that post. So when I erase the images from the post they still reflect in the gallery scroll depending on the number of items I call.

this is my code for calling attachments

```
function sunset_get_attachment($num = 1)
{
   $output = '';
   if (has_post_thumbnail() && $num == 1):
        $output = wp_get_attachment_url(get_post_thumbnail_id(get_the_ID())); else:
        $attachments = get_posts(array(
           'post_type' => 'attachment',
            'posts_per_page' => $num,
            'post_parent' => get_the_ID(),
        ));
    if ($attachments && $num == 1):
            foreach ($attachments as $attachment):
                $output = wp_get_attachment_url($attachment->ID);
    endforeach; elseif ($attachments && $num > 1):
            $output = $attachments;
    endif;

   wp_reset_postdata();

   endif;
    return $output;
}
```

**WordPress says**
You can upload images in 2 places: Media page (uploads.php) or from Add Media button in a post/page edit page. When you upload images from the post edit screen, 'post_parent' for all images uploaded is set to current post. When you upload images from the Media page, 'post_parent' is set to 0.

When an image you have uploaded on media page is first inserted in the content of a post, or is included in a gallery inside the post, the 'post_parent' field is changed to the current post, just like it was uploaded using Add Media button of post edit screen.

As you noticed this does not happen for featured images, when an image uploaded on media page is used as featured image for a post, its post_parent stay unchanged.

Only thing that change is that a meta field '_thumbnail_id' is created for the post and its value is setted to the id of attachement post.

enter image description here

So if your post id is 10, get_post_meta(10, '_thumbnail_id', true); will return the ID of the post thumbnail.

Note that an image with post_parent setted to a post id does not mean that it's inserted in the content of the post, it can be uploaded using the post Add Media button, but never inserted in the post content.

Also the countrary is true, an image inserted in the content of a post can have a post_parent setted to another post id.

**Plea**
Is there a way to call only the images in the current published post editor?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying to code around it, it is simpler to just detach the image from the post it was uploaded to. You can do this in the **Media Library**:

1. Make sure you are in **list view** and that the "**Uploaded to**" column is showing
2. There will be a **"Detach" link** in the "Uploaded to" column under the
   post name - clicking it will break the association between it and the post it was uploaded to.

FYI, an "Attach" link will be shown for images that are not associated with a post, so if you detach an image by mistake you can use it to reattach it.

Comment: I wish there was some plugin to the bulk unattach. All the ones in the repository are outdated. I have found some leads here thanks to 

https://wordpress.org/plugins/unattach-and-re-attach-attachments/

Comment: @omukiguy, the reviews on that plugin suggest it still works, so you might be lucky. Glad I was able to point you in the right direction, instead of trying to parse the post editor content for images :-)

Comment: @omukiguy Older plugins may not be secure, but you only need to use it once to detach the images (as long as you remember not to upload extra images in a post again!). So you could run WP in maintenance mode, install and use the plugin and then delete all traces of it again immediately. But if you do get your new plugin working, don't forget to add it in an answer to your own question :-)

Comment: I forked the plugin and added it to the WordPress Repo. https://wordpress.org/plugins/upgrade-for-unattach-re-attach-media-attachments/